# to convert varchar to decimal for only numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, casting, type-conversion

I have a varchar column which contains a combination of numeric, string, or both types of values. I want to find only the rows with numeric data in this column, and  then populate a new column of a decimal type with that data, converting the numeric string into a true numeric value.

Comment: uploaded the image in the following link https://ibb.co/6mH0tRL

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(decimal(10, 2), col)
```

Note:  Your scale and precision might differ.

Comment: that did not help me, Can i have you email id so that I can share you the table photo

Comment: @user8400144 . . . This should do exactly what you want.